# In Java, how detect source where int value was set to long variable

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, java-bytecode-asm

In Java, is there any tools(IDE or library) can detect(search/grep) that an int value was set to a long variable?

Sample code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int intValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        long longValue = Long.MIN_VALUE;

        // No compile error, How can I know all these codes in my project?
        longValue = intValue; 

    }
```

Thanks for any advices

Comment: I suppose you can configure an IntelliJ inspections profile to warn you about these, but I've never done that myself. https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/customizing-profiles.html

Here's a useful video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veKpWj_7QEE

Also, welcome to the 1k club!

Comment: When you say an int value was set to a long variable, do you mean `intValue = longValue`?

Comment: @Siddhartha thanks, I will try it

Comment: @sparky No, long is the variable, so it won't show compile error(intValue = longValue shows it). But I want to know such the [long = int] list in my project(millions of codes).

Comment: @Siddhartha thanks  i think i have found the answer too, please check my own answer. PS: I love 999 more than 1K

Comment: But now you get the expandable usercard!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veKpWj_7QEE), I managed to figure it out:

In IntelliJ, go to:

*Edit -> Find -> Search Structurally...*

Hit *Existing Templates*, then chose `assignments` under `expressions`

That'll give you `$Inst$ = $Expr$` in your Search template box. Now hit 
`Edit variables...`, and make `Inst`'s `Expression Type` to be `long`, and `Expr`'s to be `int`.

Search within your current file and you'll see it pull up all such assignments. Go on to convert it into an inspection profile as the video describes. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I want exactly!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution by using IntelliJ(thanks @Siddhartha)

Settings here:
[image: Option]

This is the warning:
[image]

Comment: Nice find. This is actually easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

This is ok as written because an int can cast to a long.

However, the REVERSE is not true:  a long can't be cast to an int!

Comment: Yes, I know it. but I want to show such a list in my project(millions of codes).